# Identificar sequencias de zero em um arquivo csv utilizando python

Tags: python, csv

bom dia!

Estou com dificuldade para identificar sequencias de zero em um arquivo csv, utilizando pyhton.

Abaixo um exemplo do meu arquivo csv:

```
Index       |  Ponto de Medição  |     Data    | Hora  |ZeroApply
  0         |        User1       |  31/12/2018 |  20   |   1
  1         |        User1       |  31/12/2018 |  21   |   0
  2         |        User1       |  31/12/2018 |  22   |   0
  3         |        User1       |  31/12/2018 |  23   |   0
  4         |        User1       |  31/12/2018 |  24   |   0
  5         |        User2       |  01/01/2019 |  01   |   1
  6         |        User2       |  01/01/2019 |  02   |   0
  7         |        User2       |  01/01/2019 |  03   |   0
  8         |        User2       |  01/01/2019 |  04   |   0
  9         |        User3       |  01/01/2019 |  05   |   1
```

Eu preciso gerar um alarme sempre que identificar na coluna "ZeroApply" uma sequencia de zero >= 3., e indicar o usuário que possui essa sequencia de zero, como o exemplo abaixo, inserir um "Verificar" no ultimo registro de zero da sequencia.

```
Index       |  Ponto de Medição  |     Data    | Hora  |ZeroApply |Análise
  0         |        User1       |  31/12/2018 |  20   |   1      |
  1         |        User1       |  31/12/2018 |  21   |   0      |
  2         |        User1       |  31/12/2018 |  22   |   0      |
  3         |        User1       |  31/12/2018 |  23   |   0      |
  4         |        User1       |  31/12/2018 |  24   |   0      |Verificar
  5         |        User2       |  01/01/2019 |  01   |   1      |
  6         |        User2       |  01/01/2019 |  02   |   0      |
  7         |        User2       |  01/01/2019 |  03   |   0      |
  8         |        User2       |  01/01/2019 |  04   |   0      |Verificar
  9         |        User3       |  01/01/2019 |  05   |   1      |
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar em como fazer isso?

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Você consegue colocar o link do csv?

Comment: Olá Felipe. O problema está claro. Mas, o que você já tentou fazer? Qual é a sua dificuldade? Você tem mais chances de obter ajuda se explicar a sua dificuldade e não esperar que alguém simplesmente faça pra você.

Answer (score 1):

A primeira coisa a ter em mente é que: um arquivo CSV não é "modificável" - o seu programa vai ter que gerar outro arquivo CSV, com o mesmo modelo, e os dados a mais inseridos.

No seu exemplo é fácil entender por que não se pode modificar o arquivo: as linhas de dados tem 60 caracteres - que correspondem a 60 bytes no arquivo (podem corresponder a um pouco mais bytes dependendo da codificação e da presença de caracteres especiais, mas não vem ao caso agora). Ao se adicionar uma quarta coluna, o tamanho da linha passa para 75 caracteres/bytes - acontece que no arquivo original, esses 15 bytes a mais já estão na *próxima linha*, então essa próxima linha, inclusive os caracteres marcadores de mudança de linha, seriam sobre-escritos pelos dados extras. Duas linhas se fundiriam em uma, parte dos dados seriam perdidos, etc...

Por outro lado, a criação de um novo arquivo é bem tranquila e eficiente - você pode usar arquivos CSV tranquilamente em operações com até centenas de milhares de registros, desde que não sejam feitas com frequência (ex. uma vez por requisição numa aplicação Web). Claro que a partir de um certo ponto é melhor manter tudo em banco de dados.

O que não é tão direto, a partir do Python, é gerar o arquivo CSV tão "bonitinho" quanto esses dos exemplos, com os dados centrados nas colunas, etc... mas é possível também (uma dica nesse caso é usar a biblioteca [rows](https://github.com/turicas/rows), e gerar "tabelas em texto" e não em CSV).

Essa restrição da formatação é facilmente contornável também, se for parte dos requisitos - bastando-se formatar cada campo com as funções de string ao se escrever o arquivo.

Ler e escrever o arquivo CSV como texto direto é bem fácil em Python - mas é interessante notar o módulo [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) que pode cuidar de "corner-cases" automaticamente: se o caractere separador aparece dentro de uma célula de texto, ou se alguma célula contem o caractere `"`, normalmente usado para delimitar texto, ou mesmo o caractere de mudança de linha `\n`.

Já o algoritmo em si, para detectar os zeros em seguida é trivial - é só manter um contador, zerado a cada ocorrência de um valor não-zero na posição desejada, e incrementado a cada nova linha.

Como fica mais fácil entender, vou dar exemplo de uma versão abrindo os arquivos diretamente, sem o módulo `csv` do Python. Mas em produção é interessante olhar o mesmo, especialmente se em qualquer ponto no futuro os arquivos possam ter algum dos casos "patólogicos" que eu citei em suas linhas.

```
from pathlib import Path

def main(filepath):
    inp_path = Path(filepath)
    out_path = Path(filepath + "_new")

    with inp_path.open() as inp_file, out_path.open("wt") as out_file:
        headers = next(inp_file).strip().split('|')
        new_headers = headers[:] + 'Análise'
        # O seu arquivo de exemplo tem os títulos das colunas todos bagunçados: 
        # em alguns casos é centrado com um espaço de folga, a data
        # é centrada com vários espaços de folga, algumas colunas são alinhadas
        # a esquerda, outras centradas, e outras com alinhadas a esquerda com 
        # espaços.  Como não é possível colocar isso no código sem as coisas
        # específicas de cada coluna, pode valer a pena simplesmetne 
        # escrever o cabeçalho todo como uma string fixa. Isso é bem pouco elegante,
        # mas seria:
        # out_file.write("Index       |  Ponto de Medição  |     Data    | Hora  |ZeroApply |Análise\n")
        # melhor é abrir mão da formatação maluca para cada coluna, e usar, por exemplo,
        # nomes centralizados em 12 espaços (o que permite manter a formatação da data como está)
        out_file.write("|".join(header.strip().center(12) for header in headers) + "\n")
        zero_sequence_counter = 0
        for line in inp_file:
            fields = line.split("|")
            zero_apply = int(fields[-1].strip())
            verify_field = ""
            if zero_apply == 0:
                zero_sequence_counter += 1
                if zero_sequence_counter >= 3:
                    verify_field = "Verificar"
            else:
                zero_sequence_counter = 0
            fields.append(verify_field)
            out_file.write("|".join(field.strip().center(12) for field in fields) + \n)

    # opcional: remover o arquivo original e renomear o novo arquivo:
    inp_path.unlink()
    out_path.rename(inp_path)


main("nome_do_arquivo.csv")
```

Um detalhe desse exemplo é que eu faço uso extensivo da classe `pathlib.Path` para todas as operações relacionadas a arquivo. Como é uma funcionalidade relativamente recente na linguagem, quase todos os exemplos que você encontrar de Python vão manipular arquvos sem usar a mesma - usando as funções de manipulação de string para o nome dos arquivos, e o `open` built-in para abrir um arquivo.

Fora isso, o que tem aí é uso dos métodos `.split`, `.center`, `strip` e `.join` das strings, e `+` para concatenar strings - e `int` para fazer uso da coluna como valor numérico - mas nem seria necessária essa conversão. O algoritmo em si, como descrito acima, é bem simples.

Answer (score -1):

vc pode criar um dicionario vazio ou ja com todos os usuarios, e todos apontando para o valor zero

quando vc iterar o arquivo e se o valor for zero, vc vai adicionar 1 ao usuário correspondente no dicionario, quando chegar a 3 vc manda o aviso, ou vc zera o valor no dicionario se a sequencia for quebrada